# How to prove the limit inferior of a bounded squence exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Define a sequence $b_k =$inf$ \{a_l|l\ge k \}$ for $k\ge1$. Prove that $\lim_{k\to \infty }$$b_k$ exists.

I am proving that the limit inferior exists, but I don't know where to start. How can we show the limit exists?

Comment: In most calculus-analysis courses it is assumed that if $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ is bounded then $A$ has a limit inferior (or least upper bound, as most call it).

Comment: @dREaM I assume you mean the greatest lower bound?

Comment: Since $\{a_k\}$ is bounded, so is $\{b_k\}$. By construction, $\{b_k\}$ is increasing. So you know why $\{b_k\}$ converges.

Comment: @Math1000 of course, thanks.

Comment: why is $\{b_k\}$ increasing? @user295959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that if $k\le\ell$, then $b_k\le b_\ell$. Thus, the sequence $\langle b_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a bounded, monotone non-decreasing sequence. Therefore ... ?

Comment: how do you get $b_k \le b_l$ ?

Comment: @Maggie: Let $S_k=\{a_j:j\ge k\}$; if $k\le\ell$, then $S_k\supseteq S_\ell$; thus, if $x\le s$ for each $s\in S_k$, automatically $x\le s$ for every $s\in S_\ell$. This means that every lower bound for $S_k$ is also a lower bound for $S_\ell$, and hence that $\inf S_k\le\inf S_\ell$.